# How to render JSON from a URL as HTML in React Native Text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Are we able to render a value of JSON at a specific URL in a React Native Text block?

I'm essentially wanting to render something like the following inside a view with formatting, but I'm not sure how to render the formatting correctly without using `dangerouslysetinnerhtml`.

```
{
  "field": "<h2>Heading</h2><p>Paragraph</p>"
}
```

How might one go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try his lib [string-strip-html](https://www.codsen.com/os/string-strip-html/) , it allow to clear HTML tags form string.

```
//return "Some text and text"
stripHtml(`Some text <b>and</b> text.`).result
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am wanting to display the text as styled. Not remove the tags